# How to get the values of all controls of active form in one string and concatenate them?

Tags: c#

How to get the values of all controls of active form in one string and concatenate them using C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want, but it could be something as simple as:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ProcesControls(this));
}

private string ProcesControls(Control parent)
{
    string s = "";
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (c.HasChildren)
            s+=ProcesControls(c);

        s += c.Text;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Gotta hope nobody overrides that `Text` property with a throw Exception.

Comment: Hi friend,
i simply making one user control named as toolbar.dll. the toolbar contain the add, save, update, delete and search button. to save the data of the form i want to use save button globally. for that firstly i had done the table mapping. 

But i cant understand how to get the values of control(Textbox, maskedtextbox, checkbox, combobox and datetimePicker only ) of active form and concate it with "," separator. The concatenation string pass to save query.
If u know then please help me how to do that.